# Decoding label names from an XML file

Tags: xml, decode, encode

I was going through an xml file and it had some encoding on the label names like

```
<label>534fe310-1f4f-11e5-b53a-065676001937</label>
```

does anyone know what that is ? and how do i decode it ?

Few more egs :

```
<id>d6b38cc0-9c89-11e2-af34-0025906a2be6</id>

<label>bf6e7e90-1ebd-11e5-b53a-065676001937</label>
```

Comment: They are just data so you have to know what the origination specified these to be

Comment: I don't think there is any encoding or encryption stuff here. It looks like some UUIDs https://www.uuidgenerator.net